# rand package error in Go

Tags: go

I try to call the ExpFloat64() function of the rand package (http://golang.org/pkg/rand/). However, it gives following error "prog.go:4: imported and not used: rand prog.go:7: undefined: ExpFloat64". Can anybody help me why is it giving error ? Code given below.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "rand"

func main() {
fmt.Println(ExpFloat64())
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message explains it perfectly - in Go, you can't import packages and not use them. Here, it says you're importing rand and not using it, so either use it or don't import it. Your main function should be:

```
fmt.Println(rand.ExpFloat64())
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to what Chris Bunch said, if you really wanted to use the names in the package (e.g. `ExpFloat64`) directly without using the package name, you can do this:

```
import . "rand"
```

Comment: But don't. It's only useful in rare special cases of test files; everywhere else it's a bad idea.